# Put an myObject to ObjectInputStream without using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, scala, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I want to put an object in an ObjectInputStream. I wrote the following code to write the object to an ObjectOuputStream and saved it in **"myObjectFile"**. Then read **"myObjectFile"** to get an ObjectInputStream:

```
val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myObjectFile"))
oos.writeObject(myObject);
oos.close();

val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myObjectFile"))
     :
ois.close();
```

---

Is it possible to create an ObjectInputStream for myObject directly without writing an intermediate "myObjectFile"?

---

I also tried the following:

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)
oos.writeObject(myObject);
oos.flush();
oos.close();

val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())
val ois = new ObjectInputStream(is)

println(" baos size = " + baos.size())
println(" ois size = " + IOUtils.toByteArray(ois).length)
```

---

But I got:

```
 baos size = 369
 ois size = 0
```

Why the ois size is 0? What did I do wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at `PipeInputStream` and `PipeOutputStream`.

Comment: Also `ByteArrayOutputStream`, `ByteArrayInputStream`